# Why this small c++11 multi threaded program giving segmentation fault

Tags: multithreading, c++11, race-condition, undefined-behavior

why this program giving seg fault. I tried figuring out the issue using gdb, but no luck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

condition_variable cv;
mutex cv_m;

mutex m;

int  count = 0;
#define COUNT_DONE  10
#define COUNT_HALT1  3
#define COUNT_HALT2  6

void functionCount1()
{
   for(;;)
   {
        m.lock();
        count++;
        cout << "Counter value functioncount1: " << count << endl;
        m.unlock();

        if(count >= COUNT_DONE)
                return;
    }
}

void functionCount2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        m.lock();
        count++;
        cout << "Counter value functionCount2: " << count << endl;
        m.unlock();

        if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(functionCount1), t2(functionCount2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the debugger is not helping, then you need to add logging messages, first know where the segfault is occurring.

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior: access to `count` outside the mutex is a data race. [With the UB corrected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7aeb98c985d5d27 "Live code at Coliru") it seems fine.

Comment: Please use lock classes for locking a mutex rather than exception-unsafe member functions. See this article for reference: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-lock

Comment: Why would a race on count generate a segfault?

Comment: @MartinJames a race is undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: @Casey please post this as answer, it deserves an upvote.

Comment: @TemplateRex My honest expectation is that this UB is not the true source of the problem. I think a race in the iostreams code is more likely the culprit. But I'll post an answer anyway, and edit it as needed when we get more feedback from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior: the accesses to `count` outside the mutex in `functionCount1` and `functionCount2` are data races. [With the UB corrected, it seems fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54e5d93ea6524fce):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

mutex m;
int  count = 0;
#define COUNT_DONE  10

void functionCount(const char* name)
{
   for(;;)
   {
        m.lock();
        auto c = ++count;
        m.unlock();

        cout << "Counter value " << name << ": " << c << endl;
        if(c >= COUNT_DONE)
                return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(functionCount, "functionCount1"), t2(functionCount, "functionCount2");
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

or if you want to be "clever" and confuse your code reviewers:

```
void functionCount(const char* name)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        auto c = (std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m), count++);
        cout << "Counter value " << name << ": " << c << endl;
        if(c >= count_done)
            break;
    }
}
```